# Wordpress CURL login not working

Tags: wordpress, curl

I had a curl script for a wordpress blog that just started failing. I get an error message that cookies must be enabled to login. Below is the code for logging in.

```
$post_str = 'log=USERNAME&pwd=PASSWORD&redirect_to=https://sub.wordspress.com/wp-admin/&testcookie=1&wp-submit=Log%20In';
$cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$url = "https://domain.com/wp-login.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://sub.wordpress.com/wp-admin/');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Cookie file:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.wordpress.com  TRUE    /   FALSE   0   wordpress_test_cookie   WP+Cookie+check
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Wish I had an answer, but I am having the same problem. Something changed at wordpress.com after 8/23. If anyone knows a way to get CURL or WGET logins working for wordpress.com I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

OK, maybe i do now have an answer.

My (bash) script that stopped working doesn't look much like yours.

Here was mine originally, NOT WORKING after 8/23:

```
# Set some default file names...
COOKIES="$FILEPATH/cookies.txt"

# set up login data
POSTDATA="log=${USERNAME}&pwd=${PASSWORD}"
POSTDATA="${POSTDATA}&rememberme=forever&submit=Log%20In"
POSTDATA="${POSTDATA}&redirect_to=http://wordpress.com/&testcookie=1"

#first get test cookie
curl --silent --cookie-jar "${COOKIES}" --output /dev/null "${LOGIN_URL}"

# now log in
curl --silent \
    --cookie-jar "${COOKIES}" \
    --output /dev/null \
    --max-redirs 0 \
    --data "${POSTDATA}" \
    "${LOGIN_URL}"
```

All it took to fix it was the addition of the `cookie` parameter in the second curl call like this:

```
curl --silent \
    --cookie "${COOKIES}" \
    --cookie-jar "${COOKIES}" \
    --output /dev/null \
    --max-redirs 0 \
    --data "${POSTDATA}" \
    "${LOGIN_URL}"
```

not sure 100% what that looks like in the context of your script, but maybe adding a line something like this:

`curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);`

would do it?

Comment: Thank you! Adding the `--cookie` parameter worked for [my wordpress.com export script](https://github.com/l0b0/export/commit/5c39dc3faf20b3b6c6d73075edf37b6c427f179a).